# My Combat Script in Unity is Kinda not Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm in Unity and I Wrote a Combat Script and It Works ... Kinda, Because If I Set the startTimeBtwAttack float to Any Higher 0 It Stops Working, Yes I Know My Script very very Long but if You Have Patience and Kindness Then Please Help Me, Here's The Code.

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCombat : MonoBehaviour
{
private PlayerMovement speed;

```
public bool hasSword = true;

private float timeBtwAttack;
public float startTimeBtwAttack;
public Animator animator;
public Transform attackPos;
public float attackRange;
public LayerMask whatIsEnemies;
public int damage;

public AudioSource swordSrc;
public AudioClip swordClip;

public float startDazedTime;
private float dazedTime;

private float attackTime = .25f;
private float attackCounter = .25f;

private bool isAttacking;


void Start()
{
    speed = FindObjectOfType<PlayerMovement>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (hasSword == true)
    {
        if (dazedTime <= 0)
        {
            speed.MovementSpeed = 5f;
        }else 
        {
            speed.MovementSpeed = 0f;
            dazedTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        }


        if (timeBtwAttack <= 0)
        {
            timeBtwAttack = startTimeBtwAttack;

            if(isAttacking)
            {
                attackCounter -= Time.deltaTime;

                if (attackCounter <= 0)
                {
                    animator.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
                    isAttacking = false;
                }
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
            {
                dazedTime = startDazedTime;
                attackCounter = attackTime;
                animator.SetBool("isAttacking", true);

                swordSrc.PlayOneShot(swordClip);
                
                isAttacking = true;

                Collider2D[] enemiesToDamage = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPos.position, attackRange, whatIsEnemies);
                for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToDamage.Length; i++)
            {
                enemiesToDamage[i].GetComponent<EnemyScript>().TakeDamage(damage);
            }
        }
    }else
    {
        timeBtwAttack -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    }
}

void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(attackPos.position, attackRange);
}
```

}

Comment: This isn't enough information to help provide any help. Please provide a copy of your code and some more details about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

the line `timeBtwAttack = startTimeBtwAttack;` should be inside the `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))`.

The way it is currently, you would only check for the X input in 1 frame every "startTimeBtwAttack" seconds. The cooldown should only be applied when you start the attack.

Comment: Thank you so Much!